# Show % of row in Excel, but only display one variable

Tags: sql, excel

I have a field in an Excel spreadsheet called SLA Met, that has 2 values. "Yes", "No".

I am trying to create a pivot line chart to show the Met SLA %.

I have done this by choosing the % of Row option, under 'Values Field Settings...' ShowValues As.

My issue is that I dont want to show the "No" values, but when I remove these from the table the % to row changes to 100%

How can I create a chart that just shows the "Yes" %

It needs to be in a pivot chart as, the report is configured to auto update via an ODBC connection.

Or is there a way to configure this in SQL, before I pull the data into Excel?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below query might help to find it at Database level:
SELECT (count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from testtable)) as YesSLA FROM testtable where SLA='Yes';

For Both No and Yes percentage:
SELECT (count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from testtable)) as sla FROM testtable group by SLA;